# Get data and control records using AWS DMS with Kafka as the target

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-dms

I am using SQL Server RDS as the source database and Apache-Kafka as the target in AWS DMS. I want to receive both the data and control records on every CDC changes made in the source database but I am only getting data records in case of CRUD commands and control record in case of the DDL commands. I went through the AWS DMS documentation but couldn't find anything relevant.

Is it possible to get both the control and data records in the Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get both the control and data records using aws dms.